Возвращаемое значение функции
char *time String (time_t t, char *buf) {
    struct tm *local;
    local = localtime(&t);
    strftime(buf, TIME_STRING_BUF, "%c", local);
    return  buf;
}

Что, в данном случае означает "char *time String (time_t t, char *buf)" ?
Источник: Разработка приложений в среде Linux. Джонсон, Троан.

Означает, что при переводе/редактировании (а может, и в оригинале, но тогда все равно переводчику/редактору надо копчик массировать) кто-то добавил пробел, должно быть char *timeString(time_t t, char *buf)...

Вы правы. Далее встречается функция "timeString", как аргумент функции "printf".
